# How to know if it got the row through that where clause in sql/php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I dont know if this is possible:

```
SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE barcode = '123123' OR product like '%123123%'
```

Lets say this returns 10 rows. Two out of the 10 rows got returned because they had 123123 in barcode.

Now is it possible somehow to make a alias/variable to know that it comes because the it matched the barcode.

So i can do:

```
if($MatchWasFromBarcode) {.... }
```

Or will i have to make 2 queries for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT case when barcode='your_value' then 1 else 0 end as matches_bar_code
, col1
, col2
, col3
, col4
FROM stuff 
WHERE barcode = '123123' 
OR product like '%123123%'
```

Don't do `select *`. Bad practice. List the columns you need.

Comment: Tried this too. It only returns result if it is a barcode, i want it to return results also when its not a barcode, just that the matches_bar_code should be 0 then

Comment: @Karem: Very weird, I am like 99.99999999999999999999999999999% sure it works because your where clause is doing an `OR`. Double check your query.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    barcode = '123123' AS MatchWasFromBarcode,
    col1, col2, ..., coln
FROM stuff
WHERE barcode = '123123' OR product like '%123123%'
```

For other databases change the second line to this:

```
    CASE WHEN barcode = '123123' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MatchWasFromBarcode,
```

Comment: @Markbyers i get You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*

Comment: @Markbyers ok i listed all the columns and now it only returns result if it is a barcode. I want it to return no matter what, but matchesbarcode should be 1 if it came from a barcode